# How to filter with ManyToMany field .?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

Offer has multiple products. When I try to print the details of the selected products, it shows some errors

## Model

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Offer(models.Model):
    offer = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

## Serializer

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ['name', 'price']

class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ['id', 'offer', 'products_list']
        read_only_fields = ['id']

    def get_products_list(self, instance):
            products_id = instance.products
            products = Products.objects.filter(id=products_id)

            return ProductSerializer(products, many=True).data
```

## Error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to pass a `ManyToManyManager` to your filter instead of `id` value. You can get all products using `all()` method of your manager.

```
def get_products_list(self, instance):
    products = instance.products.all()  # <- this is the issue
    return ProductSerializer(products, many=True).data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all products of a offer, you just need to use ProductSerializer in OfferSerializer

```
class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products_list = ProductSerializer(many=True)
```

By the way, query in SerializerMethodField is not good ideal, it will hit database request many time if you use serializer in list, you should try using [Django Subquery expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) in this case